# Intellij 15 XHTML color scheme

Tags: intellij-idea

I just recently upgraded from intellij 14 to intellij 15 and i exported all the settings from old IDE. Everything works fine except color scheme for xhtml files. Once I open the file it displays same color scheme as in old one but after few seconds it changes.

Here is the image of color scheme from old inteli j or the new before it changes:
[image]

And here from the new one:
[image]

Am I missing some setting?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Please let us know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an option, that Overrides your style with one pure color. Was a long search for me. Finally found the problem at:

Settings > Editor > Colors&Fonts> JSP> Action and directive content

Just delete foreground, background and inherited and it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me that happens only in my custom color theme, even though I haven't tweaked anything HTML or JSF related. It's working when I changed back to the default Darcula theme. Might be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Yes it works with default theme but not with costum ones.